# How to inject docker container url to an app?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, kafka-interactive-queries

I've an `app` deployed using docker-compose, which exposes some REST endpoints with data stored in Kafka topics. This data is accessed via [Kafka Interactive Queries](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-remote-state-stores-for-the-entire-app) and to share state across `app` instances, I need to somehow inject `app` url to each of docker containers (in other word, `app` instances need to communicate directly with each other). It can be done by explicitly declaring `app` instances and injecting to them url via environment variable, like below:

```
services:
  app1:
    image: app
    hostname: app1
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      APP_URL: 'app1:8080'

  app2:
    image: app
    hostname: app2
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    environment:
      APP_URL: 'app2:8081'
```

but the problem with this approach is that I've no auto-scaling functionality, previously configured using docker-compose and nginx:

```
services:
  app:
    image: app
    hostname: app
    expose:
      - "8080"
    environment:
      APP_URL: ???
      
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

```
user  nginx;

events {
    worker_connections   1000;
}
http {
        server {
              listen 8080;
              location / {
                proxy_pass http://app:8080;
              }
        }
}
```

Like in the title, what can I do to replace those "???" from above example config in order to let know each of my `app` instances its own container url?

Comment: you can use `links: ...`, each service (container) will know the other service by its name (the names app and nginx). You can also use networks: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/